# Adding a date to a date attribute in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to add a date of birth to each patient in my database and having issues adding a date to the `dob` attribute on each patient. When I add for ex. `Patient.first(dob: "01/25/1990")` I get an error reading `no implicit conversion of Integer into Hash`. Any ideas on how I would do so?

```
 create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.integer "age"
    t.date "dob"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

When I seeded my database, my `dob` field was `nil`

I have also tried `Patient.first(dob: Date.parse('31-12-2010'))` and still get the same error.

Comment: @WaynePhipps I've actually tried that already doing ```Patient.first(dob: Date.parse('31-12-2010'))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `first` doesn't take query arguments.
2. Your date format is ambiguous.

The [`first` finder method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) looks like:

> **first(limit = nil)**
>   Find the first record (or first `N` records if a parameter is supplied). If no order is defined it will order by primary key.

You want to use `find_by` as your `.where(...).first` shortcut.

And to avoid ambiguity with your dates, you should use `Date` objects or ISO-8601 formatted strings (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) inside the application and leave the supposedly "human friendly" formats for the very edges.

You want to say:

```
Patient.find_by(dob: '1990-01-25')
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. I was forgetting the update part. so ```Patient.first.update(dob: Date.parse('31-12-2010'))``` worked.